# Retrofit ругается на url

Tags: java, android, retrofit

Ситуация вообщем то следующая

```
public void requestAllJobs() {
    Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl(Constants.URL)
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .build();
```

Где

```
public static final String URL = "http://openapi.ro/api/addresses.json?description=Bucuresti";
```

Выдаёт следующую ошибку

> Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: baseUrl must end in /: http://openapi.ro/api/addresses.json?description=Bucuresti

Подскажите пожалуйста, в чем может быть проблема?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`baseUrl` это путь к корню API, а не URL конкретного вызова с параметрами. Вы же еще только собираете билдером экземпляр Retrofit, а не дергаете конкретный вызов.

В вашем случае `baseUrl`-ом будет `http://openapi.ro/api/`

Похоже, вы как-то неправильно пытаетесь использовать Retrofit. Пути к конкретным вызовам вы укажете в интерфейсе сервиса как-то так:

```
interface OpenApiService {
    @GET("addresses.json")
    Call<List<Job>> requestAllJobs(@Query("description") String description);
}
```

а в Retrofit зарегистрируете свой интерфейс и получите экземпляр сервиса:

```
Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
        .baseUrl("http://openapi.ro/api/")
        .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
        .build();

OpenApiService service = retrofit.create(OpenApiService.class);
```

после чего сможете его вызвать:

```
Call<List<Job>> jobs = service.requestAllJobs("Bucuresti");
```

Comment: Спасибо
Также если ссылка типа /cars&lang=ru
стоит записывать нечто:
    Call <List<TextNumeric>> getJSON(@Query("cars&lang") String cars);